# Limit input of user one per session per item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list of products in the database that I show in the GridView. Each row in the Grid has a text box and Button along with Name and description of the product. The button is used to send the comment for that specific button. Everything works fine now I want to limit the comment once per session. So a user will be able to send comment for a product and then button will be disabled. Now the products count can be 10 or 1000. What will be the best and efficient approach to achieve this. Should I save the product id and session id in the Session or in database or there can be some other easy way.

I haven't mentioned any code because I am just asking for best possible way to achieve the task.

Comment: Asking for "best possible" is moving this into opinion based territory. And I don't think anyone can really answer this question for you without knowing a great deal more about your program, which doesn't make for a good question here on Stack Overflow. Instead, you should implement whatever way seems best to you, then come here if you have *specific* problems with your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's understand the meaning of your suggestions:

### using a session:

you are opening a session key at your server and map a list of id's which already had commented. you can match a specific product against this session and determine if the product can be commented or not.

**pros:** very elegant and easy to maintence solution
**cons:** a user which request your website (say from another browser) will be able to comment product since the session is per connection and not per user

### using a database:

same as session, only the data is durable because it is stored by the database.

**pros:** full control whenever users are able to comment a product or not
**cons:** must identify each user with unique key (like id) and store that information in the db as well

### other alternatives:

**cookie on client side** - setting up a cookie that will store the information. **pros:** each machine saves it's own cookies (not the server) **cons:** each cookie need to identify the user (or else several users on the same machine will be blocked). cookies can be cleaned

**local storage on client side** - same as cookie for that matter

so it semms you will need to work for it a little bit.. or else the functionallity will be problematic in some scenarios

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining so elegantly. It is not a problem for me if the user is able to send the comment from another browser or coming back after closing the browser. My major concern was memory load and optimization. So lets suppose if there are 50 products showing at a time then I have to store 50 values in the session. When the number of users will increase then load will also increase.

Also if I chose database then there will an extra round trip to database each time. Which one is more optimized?

Comment: Also I didn't understand the local storage on client side. Why it is different from cookie?

Comment: @AdnanYaseen -- HTML5 lets you create small client side databases, which is really awesome! The downfall is that its not supported by all browsers yet. Read here for a live example: http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/

Comment: session lives on your RAM so storing lots of data there will be fatal and therefor the db solution may be safer. the local storage option is defined by html5 and should eliminate the use of cookies. right now, in most cases they are practically the same thing

Comment: about local storage: yes it rocks and it has support even for IE8 (tested it myself).. still you must identify different users or else several users will share the same configuration

Comment: Alright. Currently the cookie seems like the best option because of its compatibility and scope for single user per cookie and also for speed. But there is limitation of cookie size and that can be problematic. I have a feeling that I have to sacrifice for speed and go for the database option. Let me investigate more.